# detecting VR capable on Quest in a-frame

Tags: aframe

I tried detecting the Quest headset with aframe.utils - it comes up as no headset connected

using this code https://xr.dadako.com/famicase/dc.html

Is there a way to detect the Quest?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok I'll answer my own question here, incase someone has the same issue:

device detection through navigator.xr needs to be done in async, otherwise it will fail.